# Java applet, problem loading native dll

Tags: java, c++, html, dll, applet

I am writing a Java applet which loads dll's created in unmanaged C++. I am writing some basic test to get it loading.

Here's the code:

The DLL:

```
#define DllExport _declspec(dllexport)
DllExport int calc();


DllExport int calc() {
return 1000;
}
```

The applet:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class app extends Applet {

   int width, height;
   private native int calc();

   public void init() {
   try {
       System.loadLibrary("appletdll.dll");
       setBackground( Color.black );
   }
   catch(Exception e) {
       setBackground( Color.red );
               // for debugging, is there another way to for example print 
               // exception messages in an applet?
   }

   //width = getSize().width;
   width = calc();
   height = getSize().height;
  }

  public void paint( Graphics g ) {
     g.setColor( Color.green );
     for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) {
         g.drawLine( width, height, i * width / 10, 0 );
     }
  }
}
```

The HTML running the applet:

```
<html>
<head><title>simple page</title></head>
<body>

<applet width=400 height=400 code="app.class" archive="apptest.jar"> </applet> 

</body>
</html>
```

All I am getting when running in Firefox is a black 400x400 background.
When running in applerviewer, I get an UnsatisfiedLinkError on calc().

The .jar is signed using this guide:
http://wiki.plexinfo.net/index.php?title=How_to_sign_JAR_files

In the folder I have:
app.class,
apptest.jar,
appletdll.dll,
applet.htm,
myKeystore

I am probably doing alot wrong, I am just trying to get some basics working. I've been looking at applet+dll guides but they are mostly outdated. 
If there is anything that is not clear, just ask.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the function should be called Java_app_calc(). Second, it should take a single argument of type "JNIEnv *". That should do it.

If you run the program "javah", it can generate your C/C++ header file for you, which will help you get the function names and signatures correct. The argument is the name of a class (it operates on compiled class files:

javah app

Comment: Which function do you mean, should the function in the dll or in the java be renamed? What about the JNIEnv* argument, what do I supply there?

Comment: @KaiserJohaan You seem to miss the fundamentals of JNI. I would google for a tutorial or browse this one before even getting started http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/jniTOC.html . The JNIEnv* is provided by JVM and contains everything you need to interact with java from the native code. Having written thousands of lines of JNI code I would also suggest evaluating the alternatives... It is not very fun and it is very easy to make mistakes.

Comment: The C function should have that name -- that's the name the JVM is looking for. As @KaiserJohaan says, the argument is supplied by the JVM when it invokes your native method.

Comment: I must second Fredrik's comment. JNI is not fun. It is very error prone and limits the platform independence of Java. Read up on it, and make sure that it is the route you want to go. Another suggestion which I have found to be slightly easier than JNI is JNA. http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fjna.dev.java.net%2F&ei=2QGKTdyHE4-C0QHXkeWDDg&usg=AFQjCNH--RTu6kmd0gTxHTfE1PSF20B6oQ&sig2=ncSZ3XKrmSdcPuedR7_i6A